# How to automatically convert logical to nicely labelled factor?

Tags: r, function

I have a logical variable with a semantic variable name, like so:

```r
mtcars |>
  mutate(is_high_gear = gear > 3)
```

What I would like is a function – call it `logical_to_labelled_factor(f)` – that generically converts such a logical into a factor in which

- `TRUE` is mapped to "`name of the variable`", and
- `FALSE` is mapped to "not `name of the variable`"

so `"is_high_gear"` and `"not is_high_gear"` in the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ensym()` is the function you need to know about.  Based on the structure of the code you've given,

```
logical_to_labelled_factor <- function(v) {
  vName <- ensym(v)
  labels <- c(paste0("Not ", vName), vName)
  factor(v, labels=labels)
}

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    is_high_gear = gear > 3,
    is_high_gear = logical_to_labelled_factor(is_high_gear)
  )
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     is_high_gear
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     is_high_gear
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Not is_high_gear
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Not is_high_gear
...
```

But I think it should be possible to do something like

```
mtcars %>% logical_to_labelled_factor(is_high_gear, gear > 3)
```

Let me think about that...

**EDIT**

Having thought about it, I think this is neater:

```
neat_logical_to_labelled_factor <- function(d, v, cond) {
  vName <- ensym(v)
  labels <- c(paste0("Not ", vName), vName)
  d %>% 
    mutate(
      {{ v }} := factor( {{ cond }}, labels=labels)
    )
}

mtcars %>% neat_logical_to_labelled_factor(is_high_gear, gear > 3)

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     is_high_gear
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     is_high_gear
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Not is_high_gear
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Not is_high_gear
```

Comment: Thank you much, that works! But something seems to be going wrong when I pretty this up a bit by inserting `vName <- gsub(pattern = '_', replacement = ' ', vName)`

Comment: Well, yes, I think it would go wrong, because `is high gear` is not a valid R name. :=(.  I suspect you meant to edit `labels`, not `vName`. :=)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a one-liner and more conveniently directly without column creation function.

```
f <- \(x, u, e) {x[[u]] <- as.factor(sprintf('%s', c(paste0('not_', u), u)[eval(substitute(e), x, parent.frame()) + 1L])); x}

mtcars |> f('is_high_gear', gear > 3) |> head()
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     is_high_gear
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     is_high_gear
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     is_high_gear
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 not_is_high_gear
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 not_is_high_gear
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 not_is_high_gear
```